# Вывод одного потом другого

Tags: php

Вопрос такой: дан массив, нужно чтобы с начало выводились те слова длинна которых больше 6, а остальное ниже
И что тут не так ?

```
    <?php
$my_array=array("Washington","Jack","Harry","Jacob","Benjamin","Oscar","Jackson","Wilburn","Leo","Max");
foreach($my_array as $valuE)
{
if(strlen($valuE)>6)
   {
  print_r ($valuE);
  echo "<br>";
      }

else
   {
  print_r ($valuE);
  echo "<br>";
      }
}

?>
```

Comment: Они идут по порядку, по этому не так работает как вы хотите.

Comment: @And а как надо, чтобы работали так как мне это надо ?

Comment: Вам сначала нужно проверять все больше длиной, а потом сделать вывод всех меньших.

Comment: Можете ли Вы поправить чтобы было как надо ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не так то, что вы берете элемент, проверяете его длину и, если она больше 6, то выводите. Если меньше, то все равно выводите.

Я бы предложил отсортировать массив по длине каждого слова внутри. Затем уже можно воспользоваться выводом, где проверять длину нет необходимости (ведь элементы отсортированы)

```
$my_array= array("Washington","Jack","Harry","Jacob","Benjamin","Oscar","Jackson","Wilburn","Leo","Max");

function my_sort($a, $b) {
  return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
}

usort($my_array, 'my_sort');

foreach($my_array as $valuE) {
  print_r ($valuE);
  echo "<br>";
}
```